# Any possibility to have cosmos db image in Mac OS

Tags: mac

Just wondering is there any way to get docker image of cosmos DB and bring up a container service for it on Mac OS? 
Asking because we were using remote cosmos DB for dev before, but we have to build our project in local now for test purpose. In our case MacOS is the only choice and no VM is allowed. So I have to find a way to make use of cosmos DB in MacOS.
I know they are working on this feature continues but there's no ETA about that. Anyone has an idea to resolve this problem for now?